# TypeError: n.toLowerCase is not a function while using JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use span tags to display project number in the dropdown list but it's throwing an error.Here is my code which is causing the error. My sandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-monad-j32jn?file=/src/index.jsx:0-736)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Select } from "react-select-virtualized";
import faker from "faker";
import "./styles.css";

const optionsDefault = new Array(1000).fill(null).map(() => ({
  value: faker.random.number(),
  label: (
    //"Project # " + faker.random.number().toString()
    <>
      <span style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>
        faker.random.number().toString()
      </span>
    </>
  ),
  lang: faker.address.country()
}));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Select Virtualized Example</h1>
      <Select options={optionsDefault} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The above code works fine if I use it like this:

```
const optionsDefault = new Array(1000).fill(null).map(() => ({
  value: faker.random.number(),
  label: (
    "Project # " + faker.random.number().toString()
   
  ),
  lang: faker.address.country()
}));
```

Comment: You are using `react-virtualized-select` which uses `react-select` v1, the post you linked use v2 which is a rewrite with many API changes so I guess that's what causes the error. See the [migration guide](https://react-select.com/upgrade-guide)

Comment: @NearHuscarl Thanks for your message. So the sandbox post that I linked is from one of their (`react-select-virtualized`) examples. Does this means that they are using `react-select` v2 in their sandbox examples and v1 elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was looking at `react-virtualized-select` while yours is `react-select-virtualized`

Comment: @NearHuscarl I see. No worries. Do you think what Yu Miao mentioned in his comment below (`The label attribute cannot accept jsx in react-select-virtualized`) seems to be the issue?

Comment: I don't know what happen, but my guess is that `label` must be a string instead of a react element which does not have `.tolowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

Using variables in JSX requires curly braces.

```js
 <>
      <span style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>
        faker.random.number().toString()
      </span>
 </>
```

modified as follows：

```js
 <>
      <span style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>
        {faker.random.number().toString()}
      </span>
 </>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the codesandbox above? I tried to make the change and it's still showing same error. Let me know if I am missing anything. Here is what I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-bush-4hrqu   Thanks !

Comment: The label attribute cannot accept jsx in `react-select-virtualized`, if you want to customize the style, check this: https://react-select.com/styles#select-props